# AWS Glue job throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am running a glue ETL transformation job. This job is suppose to read data from s3 and converts to parquet.

Below is the glue source.... `sourcePath` is the location of the s3 file.

In this location we have around 100 million json files.. all of them are nested into sub-folders.

So that is the reason I am applying `exclusionPattern` to exclude and files starting with `a` (which are around 2.7 million files) and I believe that only the files starting with `a` will be processed.

```
val file_paths = Array(sourcePath)

val exclusionPattern = "\"" + sourcePath + "{[!a]}**" + "\""

glueContext
  .getSourceWithFormat(connectionType = "s3",
    options = JsonOptions(Map(
      "paths" -> file_paths, "recurse" -> true, "groupFiles" -> "inPartition", "exclusions" -> s"[$exclusionPattern]"
    )),
    format = "json",
    transformationContext = "sourceDF"
  )
  .getDynamicFrame()
  .map(transformRow, "error in row")
  .toDF()
```

After running this job with Standard worker type and with G2 worker type as well. I keep getting error

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 27788"...
```

And in the cloudwatch I can see that the driver memory is getting utilised 100% but executor memory usage is almost nil.

When running the job I am setting `spark.driver.memory=10g` and `spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4096` and --conf job parameter.

This is the details in the logs

```
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.connect.max-wait.ms=60000 
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://ip-myip.compute.internal:1111 
--conf spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address=ip-myip.compute.internal:1111 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=4 
--conf spark.executor.memory=20g 
--conf spark.executor.cores=16 
--conf spark.driver.memory=20g 
--conf spark.default.parallelism=80 
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=80 
--conf spark.network.timeout=600 
--job-bookmark-option job-bookmark-disable 
--TempDir s3://my-location/admin 
--class com.example.ETLJob 
--enable-spark-ui true 
--enable-metrics 
--JOB_ID j_111... 
--spark-event-logs-path s3://spark-ui 
--conf spark.driver.memory=20g 
--JOB_RUN_ID jr_111... 
--conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 
--scriptLocation s3://my-location/admin/Job/ETL 
--SOURCE_DATA_LOCATION s3://xyz/ 
--job-language scala 
--DESTINATION_DATA_LOCATION s3://xyz123/ 
--JOB_NAME ETL
```

Any ideas what could be the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have too many files, you are probably overwhelming the driver. Try using the `useS3ListImplementation`. This is an implementation of the Amazon S3 ListKeys operation, which splits large results sets into multiple responses.

try to add:

`"useS3ListImplementation" -> true`

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-oom-java-heap-space-error/

Comment: thanks.. @eman.. 
I am not seeing OOM errors.. but when the job start... it keeps running but there is no progress at all...

Cloudwatch shows memory usage of ~0.28 for both driver and executor.. but that is a constant for a very long time... and there is no ETL data movement or any thing...

Comment: also the executor log says 

WARN ApacheUtils: NoSuchMethodException was thrown when disabling normalizeUri. This indicates you are using an old version (< 4.5.8) of Apache http client. It is recommended to use http client version >= 4.5.9 to avoid the breaking change introduced in apache client 4.5.7 and the latency in exception handling. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919 for more information

Comment: I think you can incorporate the spark-ui as well to see what you job is actually doing. Although this is a post run assessment you could try this with a smaller dataset i.e using push down predicates. Benchmark the runs and see the allocations of DPUs that are more suited for your workload. You could also spin up a development endpoint but be careful on the DPU count as your cost can easily sky rocket.

Comment: I am running the spark ui.... but there are not tasks created, no DAG... it is all empty...
also m not sure if I can use push down predicates as the s3 file path is 
s3://bucket-name/uuid/sometext/2020/01/02.data.json

m not sure if can use push down predicates... thanks for your help...

the only thing i don't understand is why does driver and executors not doing any thing at all... the job keeps on running but no processing happening....

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @eman...

I applied all 3 groupFiles, groupSize and useS3ListImplementation.. like below

```
options = JsonOptions(Map(
            "path" -> sourcePath,
            "recurse" -> true,
            "groupFiles" -> "inPartition",
            "groupSize" -> 104857600,//100 mb
            "useS3ListImplementation" -> true
    ))
```

And that is working for me... there is also an option of "acrossPartitions" if data is not arranged properly.