# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Error in AWS Glue Job. How to Resolve?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, jvm, heap-memory, aws-glue

Hi there I Am getting an error on a glue jib which is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` I have tried the options given in the following sites:

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/glue-oom-java-heap-space-error

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-to-scale-apache-spark-jobs-and-partition-data-with-aws-glue/

[AWS Glue job throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505071/aws-glue-job-throwing-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

But getting the same error.

Below is my configuration in the AWS glue job using Python script:

```
import sys 
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, max
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
print('step 1')
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'iceberg_job_catalog_warehouse'])
conf = SparkConf()
print('step 2')
## Please make sure to pass runtime argument --iceberg_job_catalog_warehouse with value as the S3 path 
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.job_catalog.warehouse", args['iceberg_job_catalog_warehouse'])
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.job_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.job_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.job_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")
conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
conf.set("spark.sql.iceberg.handle-timestamp-without-timezone","true")
conf.set("spark.network.timeout","1000000")
conf.set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval","100000s")
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","20g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory","20g")

print('step 3')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)
print('step 4')
## Read Input Table
IncrementalInputDyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "landmarkdba", table_name = "mf_t_portfolio_rta_orders_purge", 
    additional_options = {
    'useS3ListImplementation': True,
    'recurse':True,
    'groupFiles': 'inPartition',
    'groupSize': '1048576'}).....
```

Here is an Image of the glue job details I have configured:

[image: And Here is Image of glue job details I have configured]